# Asp.net Core 3.1 controller methods with parameters from body is not working

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, kestrel-http-server

I have WebAPI that working under IIS reverce proxy. WepAPI working as windows service.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
[Route("version-post-body")]
public IActionResult VersionPost([FromBody] Test test)
{
   return Ok(test.TestString);
}

public class Test
{
   [JsonPropertyName("test")]
   public string TestString { get; set; }
}
```

IIS Rewrite

```
<rule name="MyRewrite">
   <match url="api/v2/(.*)" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:10126/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

When I send request, i get 408 HTTP Code. But if controller method does't expect parameters from body, it's working fine.

```
/// WOrk 
[HttpPost]
[Route("post-body-without-body")] 
public IActionResult Post() 
{ 
   return Ok("test"); 
}          
/// not work 
[HttpPost] 
[Route("post-body")] 
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] List<string> test) 
{ 
   return Ok(string.Join(";", test)); 
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Does the application (listening to `http://localhost:10126`) respond to requests normally? Does IIS rewrite action work?

Comment: Rewrite works. Only methods that expect parameters in the request body do not work. /// WOrk [HttpPost] [Route("post-body-without-body")] public IActionResult Post() {              return Ok("test"); }          /// not work [HttpPost] [Route("post-body")] public IActionResult Post([FromBody] List<string> test) {    return Ok(string.Join(";", test)); }

@abdusco